# How to create a random number between two values that change?

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

I have an application that is supposed to guess/figure out a number that was input by a user, and then change its guess based on a users response to its guess. The code I currently have is this.

```
public void askUsersNextChoice()
{
    if(itsGuess != itsSecretNumber)
        itsGuess = randy.nextInt(((itsLargeNumber - itsSmallNumber)) + 1) + itsSmallNumber;

    boolean myBool = true;

    while(myBool)
    {
        String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("                   My guess is: " + itsGuess + "\n\n1.) Too High?\n2.) Too Low?\n3.) Exactly Right?\n\n              Number of Guesses: " + itsTries + "\n ");
        if(s != null)
        {
            s = s.toLowerCase();
            switch(s)
            {
                case "too high":
                {
                    if(((itsLargeNumber - itsSmallNumber) + 1) < 101 && ((itsLargeNumber - itsSmallNumber) + 1) > 0)
                        itsLargeNumber = itsLargeNumber - (itsLargeNumber - itsGuess);

                    if(itsGuess == itsSecretNumber){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Don't you lie to me now...");
                        break;
                    }

                    myBool = false;
                    itsTries++;
                    break;
                }
                case "too low":
                {
                    if(((itsLargeNumber - itsSmallNumber) + 1) < 101 && ((itsLargeNumber - itsSmallNumber) + 1) > 0)
                        itsSmallNumber += itsGuess;

                    if(itsGuess == itsSecretNumber){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Don't you lie to me now...");
                        break;
                    }

                    myBool = false;
                    itsTries++;
                    break;
                }
                case "exactly right":
                {
                    myBool = false;
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that after so long it will throw the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive

It throws it at the line that generates the new guess based on whether the user said its previous guess was "too high" or "too low" I have been trying to fix this for a couple hours now with no luck. If anyone knows how to get this working properly I would appreciate the help. :)

Comment: I'd suggest using binary search (pick the midpoint rather than a random value in the range) -- you'll get to an answer faster, on average. Of course that may be boring...

If you want to stick with your current approach, I'd recommend adding some printouts to trace the program's behavior so you can see how it's changing the larger and smaller numbers. That will let you see when they're passing each other, and that in turn will  help you find why you're letting this happen.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I had it print the numbers after each time and it made me realize that if `itsSmallNumber` always adds `itsGuess` when its low eventually it COULD reach a value higher than `itsLargeNumber` to counter this I just had `itsLowNumber` become equal to `itsGuess` whenever `itsGuess` is lower than `itsSecretNumber`

Comment: basicly... im an idiot haha

Comment: *"basicly... im an idiot haha"* - Not necessarily.  But you do appear to have a *pattern* of asking Questions too soon.  And that can definitely make you *look like* an idiot.  Hint: learn how to use a debugger!!